# convert date to json date format c#

Tags: json, date, c#-4.0

Convert date to json date format c#.

I have a date format 21-01-2015. I need to change this date to 1326067200000.

```
 string date="21-01-2015";
```

I need output-1326067200000

Comment: Well what have you tried so far? Have you at least tried parsing the String to a DateTime? Note that it's rare (IME) to see JSON use *just* a number on its own. It's usually `\/Date(xxx)\/` or an ISO-8601 format, in my experience. Scott Hanselman has a blog post about it: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx Also, the value you've given is for January 2012, when treated as "milliseconds since the Unix epoch".

Answer (score 0):

```
         JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

         var json = ser.Serialize(DateTime.Now);
```